# How to write a the keyboard key mapping program in C, windows platform?

Tags: c, windows, keyboard

I asked a similar question but was criticized because I didnt explain my target clear enough.Sorry for that.

What I am going to implement in the program is to "redirect the key input from the keyboard"

For example, I want the key Q to replace key V, so once the program is started, when I use ctrl+Q is actually ctrl+V, and when I type Q in a test app, there will be a V appear. I dont need a GUI implementation but only a console. I think it should be easy but I do not know which system apis I should use to receive the key input and block it and make it another key input and send to the system.

Many thanks

Comment: you want system wide key remap?? you might want to look into registry functions of windows API

Comment: Now you're going to be criticized because you didn't use the [edit] link to improve your original question instead of asking a new, duplicate one.

Comment: Related questions: [How do I remap the keys on my keyboard?](http://superuser.com/q/448991), [How can I remap a keyboard key?](http://superuser.com/q/36920), [Change/swap keyboard keys](http://superuser.com/q/102714)